# How come Flume-NG HDFS sink does not write to file when the number of events equals or exceeds the batchSize?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am trying to configure Flume such that logs roll hourly or when they reach the default block size of HDFS (64 MB).  Below is my current configuration:

```
imp-agent.channels.imp-ch1.type = memory
imp-agent.channels.imp-ch1.capacity = 40000
imp-agent.channels.imp-ch1.transactionCapacity = 1000

imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.channels = imp-ch1
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.type = avro
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.bind = 0.0.0.0
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.port = 41414

imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.interceptors = host1 timestamp1
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.interceptors.host1.type = host
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.interceptors.host1.useIP = false
imp-agent.sources.avro-imp-source1.interceptors.timestamp1.type = timestamp

imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.channel = imp-ch1
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.type = hdfs
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://mynamenode:8020/flume/impressions/yr=%Y/mo=%m/d=%d/logger=%{host}s1/
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = Impr
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 10
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
imp-agent.sinks.hdfs-imp-sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 66584576

imp-agent.channels = imp-ch1
imp-agent.sources = avro-imp-source1
imp-agent.sinks = hdfs-imp-sink1
```

My intention with the configuration above is to write to HDFS in batches of 10 and then roll the file being written to hourly.  What I am seeing is that all of the data appears to be held in memory until since I am under 64MB until the files rolls after 1 hour.  Are there any settings I should be tweaking in order to get my desired behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "What I am seeing is that all of the data appears to be held in memory until since I am under 64MB until the files rolls after 1 hour." ? If you were expecting to see partial files in HDFS (that is, see the first 10 events before the file is rolled) then that is not possible because HDFS does not support appending to files. BatchSize parameters merely hints the number of events to collect before sending them to the HDFS over network. Let me know if this is your problem and I'll try to explain better in an answer.

Comment: From what I understand, HDFS actually does support appending as of version 0.20.x.  It is an optional configuration.  On top of that, I am pretty sure Flume is taking some actions to have the file open on HDFS and some of the events sent over without closing the file.

Comment: "What I am seeing is that all of the data appears to be held in memory" - How are you determining this? Note that in-progress files on HDFS, being open, may often report a length of 0 even if they have a block being written presently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, Flume is writing the data to HDFS in batches.  The file length is reported as open because a block is in process of being written to.